# Nhibernate, WindsorContainer , ASP.NET and Multitenancy

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

We are trying to achieve the multitenancy  in our asp.net (Web forms) application. We are providing separate database for each tenant.  We have one master database which stores the configuration string for tenant databases.
We are using Application_start (Global.asax) to go trough all connection strings and inject all session (alias) for each tenant. Every thing works fine.

We wanted to introduce the capability where we just create new tenant database  and connection strings for it in master database and application should be able to serve new tenant without restarting Website(IIS restart).

Can I get some hint how can I achieve it without restarting web site?

Thanks

Shishir Kumar Mishra

Comment: each connection string corresponds to its configuration & sessionfactory, thus if intention to have a database specific to each tenant, you would need enable your application to initialize the configuration & sessionfactory for the said tenant as per the requirements.

Comment: Kalki you are right and this is what we have been doing. 
In my case the intention is create tenant's database on fly and we dont want to restart the application. We want to achieve something like http://www.teamlab.com/

Comment: You will not have to re-start you application provided your application infrastructure supports tenant based session factory / session generation, simply put each tenant has it's own unique id, you use this key to fetch/initialize corresponding sessionfactory, then subsequently you open a session.

Comment: Kalki,
We already have that system. Let me put in this way . Right now we know all the tenant so we can do all this in application start. But lets say after 6 month some new tenant needs to be integrated and we have to create database and connection string for it and save it in master database. At that moment we don't want to restart the application. Do you know any link or sample source which can guide me to achieve that?

Comment: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-programmatic

Answer (score 0):

Although this implementation is about testing with an embedded database, but it should be enough to give you an idea.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18348/TDD-using-SqlCE-and-NHibernate